# SimpleDateFormatter returns date in wrong format

Tags: android, date, calendar, simpledateformat

I have a *DateTimehelper.class* in which i have performed some date related operation and the code was working fine until i get issue from customer that they are getting date in wrong format.following is  my class:

```
public class DateTimeHelper {

    private static Calendar cal;
    public static DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    public static DateFormat shortDateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    public static DateFormat shortDateFormatterWithSlash = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    public static DateFormat dateFormat_dd_MM_yyyy = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    DateTimeHelper helper;

    /**
     * set UTC Date to the calendar instance
     * 
     * @param strDate
     *            date to set
     */
    public static void setDate(String strDate) {

        try {

            Date date = (Date) formatter.parse(strDate);
            cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(date);
            updateDateTime();
        }
        catch (ParseException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * update date every 1 second
     */
    private static void updateDateTime() {

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {

                    cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 1);
                                            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                                    }
                                catch (Exception e) {

                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
            }
        });
    }

    /***
     * get updated date from calendar in custom date format
     * 
     * @return date
     */
    public static String getDate() {

        String strDate = null;
        try     {

            strDate = formatter.format(cal.getTime());
        }
        catch (Exception e) {

            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return strDate;
    }
}
```

When See the logs I found date in format:`2014-0011-25 04:45:38` which is completely wrong I guess because month should be 11 instead of 0011.

But when I tried to validate this date using the below function;it says that date is valid.

```
public static boolean isValidDate(String inDate) {

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    dateFormat.setLenient(false);
    try {

        dateFormat.parse(inDate.trim());
    } catch (ParseException pe) {

        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

How can it be a valid date?
Why I am getting date in wrong format?

This issue is very random as it is reported by only user but I  am very surprised by the behavior of *SimpleDateFormater* and *Calendar* API

Please help.

Comment: i think that calendar of yours is creating the issue

Comment: I think it is a race condition because Calender and SimpleDateFormat is not thread-safe. Your variables are static and you are using Runnable which runs on another thread.

Comment: But how can 2014-0011-25 is valid date?

Answer (score 2):

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
```

**try this see if it works**

Comment: you are using capital HH not hh use small letters